# How to set an object key inside a state object in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, object, react-hooks, spread

How can I update a react hooks state object that has a nested object containing objects with index keys? 
Here is the default state object.

```
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
      name:'',
      price:'',
      effects:{
          0:{},
          1:{},
      }

  })
```

My goal is to update the first key in the *effects* object. 
I have tried some code like this.

```
const variable = "Sleepy"
const variableObject = {[variable]:0} 
setForm({...form, ...{...form.effects, ...{0:{ variableObject }} }  })
```

This attempt places the object outside of the nested *effects* object like this.

```
{
  0:{"Sleepy":0},
  1:{},
  name:'',
  price:'',
  effects:{
    0:{},
    1:{},
  } 
}
```

Instead, the final object state should look like this.

```
{
  name:'',
  price:'',
  effects:{
    0:{"Sleepy":0},
    1:{},
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
form.effects[0].Sleepy = 0;
setForm({...form});
```

Comment: Final usage with your answer... 
`onSelect={(_, x) => ((form.effects[0][x.value] = 0),(setForm({...form})))}`

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for is something like this,

```
            ...form,
            effects:{
                ...form.effects,
                0: {...variableObject}
            }
        })
```

the spread operator inverts the packing of the object to open it inside out.
So opening a layer, we could access the key-value pairs directly.
.
Also, there is yet another approach that might help you in the long run.

```
    setForm((oldForm)=>{ 
        return oldForm.effects.0 = variableObject 
    })
```

Notice you can also use the shorthand notation to reduce the amount of code you can write. Here i included the return clause to clarify the working of setState with callback.
Anyways, here is the shorthand notation.
`setForm((oldForm)=> oldForm.effects.0 = variableObject)`
.
Have a nice day